# I want a CGI to display script results with different font sizes according to # of characters

Tags: linux, bash, http

I have a bash script which searchs on a directory given as a parameter for files ending on ".info".

The script additionally shows the file size on bytes at the beginning:

Example:

150 /home/user/file.info

I have a local Apache web server and a CGI to run the created script in order to display results via web browser.

What I want to accomplish, is to, depending on the file size, to display the results on different font sizes, for example:

150 /home/user/file.info

1500 /home/user/file2.info (This one will have bigger font)

15000 /home/user/file3.info (This one will have even a bigger font)

My current CGI Code is: (And everything works perfect, except this part, which I cant come up with)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Content-type: text/html
echo
echo "<HTML>"
echo "<HEAD>"
echo "<TITLE>CGI DEL OBLIGATORIO</TITLE>"
echo "</HEAD>"
echo "<BODY>"
echo "<BR>"
PRUEBA=`echo $QUERY_STRING|grep ^urgentes=`
TEST=`echo $QUERY_STRING|cut -d\& -f2|grep =$`
if [ $TEST = "directorio=" ]
then
    echo "Favor ingresar un directorio 'no vacio'"
    echo "<BR>"
else
    directory=`echo $QUERY_STRING|cut -d\& -f2|cut -d= -f2|sed 's/\%2F/\//g'|sed 's/\+/\ /g'`
    if [ -z "$PRUEBA" ]
        then
        echo "Se buscaran todos los requeriminentos en el directorio: $directory"
        echo "<BR>"
    else
        echo "Solo se buscaran requerimientos urgentes en el directorio: $directory"
        echo "<BR>"
        urgente="-u"
    fi
fi
echo "<BR>"
echo "<HR>"
echo "<BR>"
OIFS=$IFS
IFS="
"
if [ $TEST = "directorio=" ]
then
    if [ -z "$PRUEBA" ]
    then
        for i in `/Obligatorio/scripts/nonono 2>&1`
        do
            echo $i "<BR>"
            echo "<BR>"
        done
    else
        for i in `/Obligatorio/scripts/nonono $urgente 2>&1`
        do
            echo $i "<BR>"
            echo "<BR>"
        done    
    fi          
else
    if [ -z "$PRUEBA" ]
    then
        for i in `/Obligatorio/scripts/nonono "$directory" 2>&1`
        do
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]
            then
            echo $i "<BR>"
            else
            echo "<a href="http://obligatorio/formulario.htm">Volver al formulario</a>"
            echo "<BR>"
            fi
        done
    else
        for i in `/Obligatorio/scripts/nonono $urgente "$directory" 2>&1`
        do
            echo $i "<BR>"
            echo "<BR>"
        done    
    fi
fi

echo "<BR>"
echo "Esperamos que el resultado haya sido de su agrado"
echo "<BR>"
echo "</BODY>"
echo "</HTML>"
```

By the way, the script name is "nonono" and it is located on /Obligatorio/scripts.

Thank you so much for all the community support!

If any other information is needed for help to be provided, please feel free to ask!

Comment: After checking the file size, use [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS). For example, to increase the font `<div style="font-size:1.2em">1500 /path/to/file</div>`.